# How to extract key-value pair from nested json

Tags: json, flatten

I have as nested json object like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "name": "Product",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 50,
            "parentId": 1,
            "name": "Bicycle",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 100,
                    "parentId": 50,
                    "name": "Tire"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Oddly I have figured out how to build the nested tree from the result but not how to reverse it.

I have tried using `lodash _.flatten and _.flattendeep` but having one of those days where I can't get my head around this. Also the object can be of unknown depth. Any thoughts ?

My desired result is this.

```
[
    {"id" : 1, "parentId" : null, "Product" },
    {"id" : 50, "parentId" : 1 , "Bicycle"},
    {"id" : 100, "parentId" : 50 , "Tire"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

not a very optimal solution but just an idea, NOTE: if dataset is very large there might be some performance issues.

```
resultsArray = [];
function flatten(obj) {
    const { id, parentId, name, children} = obj;
    if(children && children.length) {
        children.map(child => flatten(child));
    }
    resultsArray.push({id, parentId, name});
}
```